# how can i split an image based on longest horizontal edge?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

For example , how can i split the two row of books of this shelf based on horizontal edge? I have used sobel edge detector to detect the edges but i don't know how to or what condition to use to split the image.

[image]

Comment: "_split the two row of books of this shelf_" ... the image is missing. Could you post the code you have so far?

Comment: and an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: @il_raffa - The image URL was in the post but it wasn't displayed due to the user's low rep.  I've added it in.

Comment: So what exactly is the expected output?  Do you want to find the border that separates the books?... do you want to segment the image into two different images?  Please provide more information.

Comment: I want to segment the image into two different image based on the bookshelf row....so far i have been able to detect the horizontal edges using sobel operator....but i don't know how to segment the image according to the longest horizontal edge @rayryeng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you two different approach to solve this problem.

1) Machine learning approach. This requires some labeled data, indicating the y coordinate of the edge position, then HOG feature plus a random forest classifier will do the job.

2) Image processing approach. First, let's see the output of [what i have done](https://github.com/liyongsea/horizontal_split/blob/master/h_edge.ipynb):

[image]

the blue color indicating the score of being the desired y position of the separation edge.

Such approach always relies on some assumptions on your data, here we suppose that the target horizontal edge separating books, which contains a lot of vertical lines. Namely, we are looking for y coordinate **where locate long horizontal lines which are not cut by vertical lines**.

Once define our objective, the rest begin very easy.

First we need a straight line detector, [hough transform](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_line_hough_transform.html) will do.

[image]

Secondly, we vote for each y coordinates for being the best separator using two scores:

1) 1st score describes how many long **horizontal** lines (found previously) are located in the neighborhood. Let's call it *s_h*.

2) 2nd score describes how many long **vertical** lines are located in the neighborhood. Let's call it *s_v*.

[image]

Finally, we only need to combine *s_v* and *s_h* to make a final score. For example,

*s = s_h / (s_v + 1)*

Using this, we get the first scoring map posted at the beginning. Some further post processing need to be done, but should not be difficult.

Here is just one possibility to solve it, here you find [my code presented in a notebook](https://github.com/liyongsea/horizontal_split/blob/master/h_edge.ipynb).

Comment: It would be good if you provided the code so that anyone else can reproduce what you've generated. Remember, when you write an answer, not only are you helping the OP with their problem, but you are potentially helping future visitors to this question who may have the same problem.

Comment: I have added a link to an ipython notebook to show how it works. But what i have done tends to overfit on this image, one need to switch certain details to make it more stable. However, if you can have more image like this (like 100?), i strongly recommend you to adapt the machine learning approach.

Comment: It would have been better if you did this in MATLAB as that is what the question was tagged under, but an IP notebook is better than nothing!... Definitely more than deserved for the OP